# How to add a dynamic view in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a program that can generate questionnaires. Under the last question you can add a new question. You determine the type of this in advance. (think of radio, checkbox or open + much more). After the Add button is clicked, a ViewModel (derived from IQuestionVM) is created and placed in the ObservableCollection (QuestionViewModels).

In the view, must be added a different view per question type. In the grid there is a binding on all QuestionViewModels. A new line is added to the grid for each new question. However, not the correct view is loaded in the grid but the standard QuestionRadioView. Each QuestionViewModel has a type that indicates what the question type is.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionOpen" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:QuestionOpenViewModel}">
        <local:QuestionOpenView></local:QuestionOpenView>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionRadio" DataType="{x:Type viewModel:QuestionRadioViewModel}">
        <local:QuestionRadioView></local:QuestionRadioView>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the code for the grid.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionViewModels}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Name="view"
                                Content="{Binding}"
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionRadio}" 
                                />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=QuestionViewModels[1].Type}" Value="Radio">
                        <Setter TargetName="view" 
                                Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource QuestionRadio}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=QuestionViewModels[1].Type}" Value="Open">
                        <Setter TargetName="view" 
                                Property="ContentTemplate"
                                Value="{StaticResource QuestionOpen}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, this is well suited for a `DataTemplate` selector.

Just add a `TemplateSelector` class with the needed `DataTemplates` properties:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate QuestionOpenTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate QuestionRadioTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is QuestionOpenViewModel)
            return QuestionOpenTemplate;
        if (item is QuestionRadioViewModel)
            return QuestionRadioTemplate;
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Then update your XAML to use the `ContentTemplateSelector` instead:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionOpenTemplate" >
        <CheckBox/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="QuestionRadioTemplate" >
        <RadioButton/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <yrNameSpace:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
                                    QuestionOpenTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionOpenTemplate}"
                                    QuestionRadioTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionRadioTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionViewModels}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"  Name="view" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"

                        />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```